# controls to make extendable zone

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, asp.net, wss

I'm making a setting page in my SharePoint site and there is a lot of setting zone on this page, so I'm thinking what's the asp or SharePoint control that makes each zone appears just by clicking on the plus mark next to its title,
I want it something like that:

```
#region
//Code
#endregion
```

except for code, there are controls and it's a UI zone! any help, please